# Outlook 2016: VBA/Macro to create a meeting with a signature

Tags: vba, outlook, skype, signature

I would like to know how to create a "meeting button" in outlook that behaves like the skype-meeting button.

Basically a button that opens a meeting window with a predetermined signature

Ps. I've tried google and searching here

/Frans Rydell

Answer (score 0):

In fact, as I understand, you mentioned "meeting button" is still call Skype-meeting feature. Maybe you could refer to this link:

[Automatically click the New Online Meeting button using VBA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4933d046-b7d9-4b7b-ade8-ac806134ffbd/create-lync-2010-online-meeting-using-vba-in-outlook-2010?forum=outlookdev)

Comment: Thank you for the link but I could not manage to use what I found there to create a meeting button with a signature